# Python constructor confusion

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm playing with python trying to create a basic repository class (normally a C++/C# for work) and am having an issue.
The following code has bombs out on
a = officesRepo(conn) saying "Too many positional arguments for constructor call", but it's being given the only argument specified, the MySql connection object.
I'm coding in vscode on linux using python3.8.  I'm wondering if pylint is expecting me to pass in "self", when I don't think it's needed.
Any help/advice/tips greatly received.  Flame away if you like, as long as it teaches me something! ;-)

```
import pymysql.cursors
import Pocos

class officesRepo:

    def __init__(conn):
        self.conn = conn


    def create(office):
        pass

    def getAll():    
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        SQL = "SELECT `officeCode`, `city`, `phone`, `addressLine1`, `addressLine2`, `state`, `country`, `postalCode`, `territory` "
        SQL += "FROM `offices`"
        cursor.execute(SQL)
        #result = cursor.fetchone()
        ret = []
        for val in cursor:
            ret.append(ret.append(val["officeCode"], val["city"], val["phone"], val["addressLine1"], val["addressLine2"], val["state"], val["country"], val["postalCode"], val["territory"]))
            
        return ret

    def getById(id):
        pass
        
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                            user='user',
                            password='password',
                            db='classicmodel',
                            charset='utf8mb4',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)    

a = officesRepo(conn) 
b = a.getAll()
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of an instance method is `self`. You don't need to pass it explicitly, but you do need to include it in the parameter list. Right now though, the `conn` parameter is acting as `self`, then there's no other parameters after that (thus the error).

You'd need

```
def __init__(self, conn):
    . . .
```

then similarly for the other methods. All instance methods require an explicit `self` parameter.

Comment: Confusing, thought self was implied in python3 and not compulsory!  You're clearly correct, but now I'm getting an error on the next line :      b = a.getAll()
TypeError: getAll() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.  Adding self to the arguments seems to get me past this.  I'm clearly "self" challenged here!

Comment: @JimTench It's implied when calling. `obj.x(1)` automatically passes `obj` as the `self` parameter. It's roughly equivalent to `TheClass.x(obj, 1)`, if you wanted to pass it explicitly. It was decided though that the object itself should be an explicit parameter of the method.

Comment: And for the other error, note my "then similarly for the other methods." suggestion at the bottom of the answer. All instance parameters require a `self` parameter.

Comment: Thank you Carcigenicate, this has solved my issue and I've accepted your answer.  I have other issues in the code, but I'll have a bash at those myself now ;-)

Comment: @JimTench Whoops, sorry, that should say "all instance methods require a self parameter". And glad it's working.